# Can't interact with java process when attaching

Tags: docker

So I'm running a java program (Minecraft) using
CMD /launch.sh

which contains: java -jar .jar

The .jar file runs, and with the docker attach command I can view all of the System.out.printLn() output - however, I cannot type into the console as is intended when usually running the jar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: which docker command and parameters are you using to run the container ? Is something like this : `docker run -it  your_image parameters-to-java-program` ?

Comment: Thanks, I've approved the other answer, but appreciate yours too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters `-i -t` need to be on the initial `docker run` to allow input and to provide a tty when you `attach`.

You may want to use `docker exec` instead of attach.